# Is there a easy way to display all contents of all files with a recursive mode in one directory?

Tags: linux, bash

Provided that I have the following directory structure:

```
.
├── 2.txt
├── 3.txt
└── a
    └── 1.txt
```

Now I want to display all contents of all files in this directory, which considered recursion. The possible format displaying like bellow:

```
a/1.txt:

...the content of 1.txt

2.txt:

...the content of 2.txt

3.txt:

...the content of 3.txt
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `find` command with `-exec` option to run the `cat` command on all the files listed, in your case, all the text files,

```
find  . -name "*.txt" -print -exec cat "{}" \;
```

Run this command from the top folder containing the files `2.txt` and `3.txt` it should display all your file contents with name as you needed.